# One-to-many and one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this one-to-many and one-to-many relationship with entity framework and I had a hard time retrieving it using eager loading, this is the sample:

**User** has one to many relationship with **Classmates** which has one to many relationship with **Items**.

I'm trying to retrieve it as:

```
context.User.Include("Classmates").Include("Items").SingleOrDefault(n => n.username == "test");
```

But it issues and exception, I'am using entity framework 4.0 (ObjectContext).
Thank you in advance guys!

**Edit:**

The exception is **A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'User' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Items'.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the answer here, sorry because I never heard of the term "Eager loading on multiple levels".

Here is the solution:

```
context.User.Include("Classmates.Items").SingleOrDefault(n => n.username == "test");
```

Here is the link for more articles regarding this problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx